# Como fazer uma consulta mysql semanal

Tags: php, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Bom dia a todos! Gostaria de um Help!!!

Estou na duvida de como fazer uma consulta mysql semanal, começando na segunda e finalizando no domingo, sendo que os dados vai ser inserido todos os dias, e a partir que os dados for inserido vai somando um valor e quando for na segunda feira ele começa a soma novamente, **sendo que ele não pode somar com a semana anterior**

exemplo da consulta que eu fiz, mas não estou obtendo êxito:

```
SELECT id, data, valor 
FROM pagamento 
WHERE WEEK(data ,7) = WEEK(NOW())
  AND reftype = 'credito'
  AND status != 99
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você tentou week(NOW(), 7), para que ambas as contagens tenham o mesmo início?

Comment: ja sim, nao dar certo.

Comment: E você chegou a imprimir o resultado de suas funções e se efetivamente existem dados para os demais dias da semana?

Comment: sim, eu coloquei os dados do dia 27/05/2019 ate o dia 03/06/2019 e ele me retornou ate o dia 02/06/2019, como já inserir um dados de outra segunda feira que no caso é o dia 03, ele era para retornar so o valor do dia 03 ou não?

Comment: Não, dia 03 já não pertence a semana do dia de hoje (supondo que hoje seja 27/05/2019).

Comment: entao quando for na segunda dia 03/06/2019 ele vai somar do dia 03/06 em diante?

Comment: Não, sua query não faz isso, ela apenas lista as linhas da semana corrente (com as restrições acima). Ela também não soma nada.

Comment: Tente um  Group By com Rollup , e diga o que deu errado.

Comment: entao, eu sei que para somar vou ter que colocar sum(valor), quero listar primeiro para ver se esta vindo correto os dados da semana

Comment: Por acaso você quer obter os totais por semana de todos os dados existentes em sua tabela e que o início de cada semana seja considerado a segunda-feira?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode criar uma função para calcular o primeiro dia da semana:

```
CREATE FUNCTION PRIMEIRO_DIA_DA_SEMANA(dia DATE)
RETURNS DATE DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  RETURN SUBDATE(dia, WEEKDAY(dia));
END
```

E depois utilizar para pegar os valores entre esta data:

```
SELECT p.id,
       p.data,
       p.valor
FROM pagamento
WHERE reftype = 'credito'
  AND status <> 99
  AND p.data >= PRIMEIRO_DIA_DA_SEMANA(NOW())
  AND p.data < PRIMEIRO_DIA_DA_SEMANA(DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 WEEK))
```

E para  conseguir o total você precisa apenas do `SUM` do valor:

```
SELECT SUM(p.valor) AS total
FROM pagamento
WHERE reftype = 'credito'
  AND status <> 99
  AND p.data >= PRIMEIRO_DIA_DA_SEMANA(NOW())
  AND p.data < PRIMEIRO_DIA_DA_SEMANA(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK))
```

---

Referência: [**How do I get the first day of the week of a date in mysql?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11229880/3388148)

Comment: Bom dia, funcionou aqui!!!, obrigado pela o empenho e dedicação.